# How to I plug in script to YML file i.e. config.yml (CircleCI) and in github action

Tags: yaml, github-actions, circleci

I have the following shell script:

```sh
    for var in $(curl -u "abc_oOQxMv:tgMn6FYCKJcd6ujuDLEK" -X GET "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/recent_apps" | jq '.[] | select(.custom_id =="android")' | jq -r '.app_id')
    do
      echo "Deleting $var"
      curl -u "abc_oOQxMv:tgMn6FYCKJcd6ujuDLEK" -X DELETE "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/app/delete/$var"
    done
```

**How do I write it into a YML file (i.e. config.yml in CircleCI) in Github Action?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run multiline commands in the workflow yaml file using `run : |` (with pipe) in a step.

**For example:**

```yaml
script-job:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - name: Run my script
      shell: bash
      run: |
        for var in $(curl -u "abc_oOQxMv:tgMn6FYCKJcd6ujuDLEK" -X GET 
           "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/recent_apps" | jq '.[] | select(.custom_id =="android")' | jq -r '.app_id')
        do
           echo "Deleting $var"
           curl -u "abc_oOQxMv:tgMn6FYCKJcd6ujuDLEK" -X DELETE "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/app/delete/$var"
        done
```